# Mapping Function keys with Shift or Command in Terminal app for vim

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, shortcut

I want to map the combination of functions keys and shift/command to make a toggle for vim in macOS default Terminal app.

For example,

```
map <S-F5> [something Toggle]
```

or

```
map <C-S-F5> [something Toggle]
```

However, in Terminal app, the combination of F5 (~F11) and shift key is simply indicated as tilde (~), so the contents in text files opened with vim become capitalized. In addition, `Cmd+F5` is the shorcut for VoiceOver, that's why I cannot use `<C-S-F5>` for my toggle.

If anyone have an idea, please answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should assume that Vim sees the output of the modified keys, not what modifier or key was used. For example, in most context, Vim would see `A` when you press `Shift+A`, not `<Shift>` and `A`. If your terminal or OS or whatever is set up to send `)` when you press `Shift+A`, then Vim will see `)` and have no idea about what you did to send it that `)`.

One consequence of that design is a) that a key combo has to send *something* for it to be mappable, and b) that the "something" in question is distinguishable from other "somethings" sent by other combos.

In practice, TUI Vim is unable to distinguish between `<F5>`, `<S-F5>`, and `<C-S-F5>`, which all send the same character sequence.

FWIW, `<C-` is the notation for `Ctrl`. The notation for `Cmd` is `<D-` but TUI Vim never receives `Cmd` so you can't use it anyway.

So you can basically forget about:

- Shift+Function key,
- Ctrl+Function key,
- Ctrl+Shift+Function key,
- Cmd+anything.

NOTE: `:help modifyOtherKeys` has recently been added but it seemed to break more things than it fixed in my limited testing. YMMV.

Comment: Very useful answer! I have not understand why my TUI Vim was not working as I expected, until your reponse. I might find different way. Thanks again!